# New column named Age by adding a year since first appearance in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like

```
ID        Date           Student_ID      
1         1/1/2023       1                    
1         1/1/2023       2                    
1         1/1/2023       3                    
1         1/1/2023       4                    
2         11/9/2022      1                    
2         11/9/2022      2                    
2         11/9/2022      3                    
3         17/4/2022      5                    
3         17/4/2022      2                    
3         17/4/2022      3                    
3         17/4/2022      4                    
4         1/3/2022       1                    
4         1/3/2022       2                    
5         1/1/2021       1                    
5         1/1/2021       2                    
5         1/1/2021       3
```

And I want to add a new column called `Age` which is equal to 2 if that student ID first appeared, and then add 1 to it every after year. So the desired outcome looks like:

```
ID        Date           Student_ID      Age
1         1/1/2023       1               4     
1         1/1/2023       2               4     
1         1/1/2023       3               4     
1         1/1/2023       4               3     
2         11/9/2022      1               3     
2         11/9/2022      2               3     
2         11/9/2022      3               3     
3         17/4/2022      5               2     
3         17/4/2022      2               3     
3         17/4/2022      3               3     
3         17/4/2022      4               2     
4         1/3/2022       1               3     
4         1/3/2022       2               3     
5         1/1/2021       1               2     
5         1/1/2021       2               2     
5         1/1/2021       3               2
```

Comment: Is it possible that a Student_ID could skip a year?

Comment: @Nick yes, in my actual dataset, some Student_ID might skip some years, e.g. first appeared in 2021, then appear few years later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. My output is slightly different from your suggested because in `2` there are same year in 3 rows `5,8,12`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.sort_values(['Student_ID', 'Date'])
# Extract year
df['year'] = df['Date'].dt.year

# Generate cumulative counts based on unique years
df['age'] = df.groupby('Student_ID')['year'].transform(lambda x: (x != x.shift()).cumsum()) + 1

    ID       Date  Student_ID  year  age
0    1 2023-01-01           1  2023    4
1    1 2023-01-01           2  2023    4
2    1 2023-01-01           3  2023    4
3    1 2023-01-01           4  2023    3
4    2 2022-09-11           1  2022    3
5    2 2022-09-11           2  2022    3
6    2 2022-09-11           3  2022    3
8    3 2022-04-17           2  2022    3
9    3 2022-04-17           3  2022    3
10   3 2022-04-17           4  2022    2
7    3 2022-04-17           5  2022    2
11   4 2022-03-01           1  2022    3
12   4 2022-03-01           2  2022    3
13   5 2021-01-01           1  2021    2
14   5 2021-01-01           2  2021    2
15   5 2021-01-01           3  2021    2
```

Comment: Hi @ragas, thank you for your reply but I want the age to increase only when the year changed, so for example although student 1 appeared two times in 2022 (ID = 4 and 11), the age for student 1 in row 4 and 11 should both be 3.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not the most resource-saving approach, but does the job.
Leaves plenty of room for improvement based on data set size.

Also could have done more steps at once - but thought this makes it a bit more readable:

```
def first_year(student_id: int) -> int:
    """Calculate the first year of each Student (ID)"""
    return df.loc[df['Student_ID'] == student_id, 'year'].min()


def calc_age(x: pd.Series) -> int:
    """
    If the current year is its first year, set the age to 2 (as per
    your Example).
    Else, add the difference of the current year and its first year.
    """
    if x['year'] == x['first_year']:
        return 2
    else:
        return 2 + (x['year'] - x['first_year'])


df['year'] = df['Date'].dt.year
df['first_year'] = df.apply(lambda x: first_year(x['id']), axis=1)
df['age'] = df.apply(lambda x: calc_age(x), axis=1)

# delete the column 'first_year' again afterwards if desired
del df['first_year']
```